# Defining morphisms on sets that have functional elements mapping to/from them

Tags: functions, reference-request

I want to define sets where each element can be a function mapping from its respective set. For instance, if one defines each element with a functional and state component:

- For a set of static elements like $S = \{1,2,3,4\}$ which is a shorthand for all functional components being equivalent to the identity function on the state component e.g. $S = \{id|1,id|2,id|3,id|4\}$

  One can show $\{1,2,3,4\} \mapsto \{1,2,3,4\}$

Now let's define $\sigma$ as a function that maps the sum of all state components outside its element to the state of its element across a morphism such that:

- For the set $S = \{\sigma|1, 2, 3, 4 \}$

  $\{\sigma| 1,2,3,4\} \mapsto \{\sigma| 9,2,3,4\} \mapsto \{\sigma| 9,2,3,4\}$
- And for a set $S = \{\sigma| 1, \sigma| 2, 3, 4 \}$

  $\{\sigma| 1,\sigma|2,3,4\} \mapsto \{\sigma | 9,\sigma| 8,3,4\} \mapsto \{\sigma| 15,\sigma| 16,3,4\}$

Alternatively one can do away with components for something like below, with $\sigma$ being a function that maps the sum of all other elements to a new element, without mapping itself:

- For the set $S = \{\sigma, 2, 3, 4\}$

  $\{\sigma,2,3,4\} \mapsto \{ 9,2,3,4\} \mapsto \{9,2,3,4\}$

If one wants to show a set like $S = \{\sigma_1, \sigma_2, 3, 4\}$ then one can add conditions to definition of $\sigma$ e.g. sum of all other elements given they are real numbers, otherwise a default value, or sum of only the real numbers in the set.

Say $\sigma_1$ maps to 1 if not all of the other elements are real, and $\sigma_2$ maps to sum of only the reals such that:
$\{\sigma_1, \sigma_2, 3, 4\} \mapsto \{1, 7, 3, 4\}$

One could also go deeper with elements that map to multiple elements or no elements, elements that map to themselves conditionally for something like $f\rightarrow 5 \iff 3 \in S \ \vee f \rightarrow f$ etc.

I have been trying to find literature studying concepts along these lines, most likely linked to functional analysis, operator theory or category theory but so far have been unsuccessful. Where should I look? Also, in the worst case scenario there is nothing to reference along these lines at all, where can I branch off from?

Comment: You are using $\to$ in seemingly two different ways, neither of which are the "standard" way and neither of which are defined. You just say that $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is shorthand for $\{\{\}\to 1,\{\}\to 2,\{\}\to 3,\{\}\to 4\}$ without ever saying what this is supposed to mean. I also strongly feel that there is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) happening here.

Comment: $\rightarrow$ in both cases means maps to. In case of the empty set maps to, I was hoping it would show those elements as having no functional component. Will edit to clarify. As for the XY problem, I would say it has to do with the nature of what I am asking: I am looking for a reference to a concept I have the intuition for, and hoping to convey it by showing a mock-solution

Comment: You can use (`\mapsto`) to get $\mapsto$, but even with that interpretation your use of the notation is confusing and used in seemingly two different ways.

Comment: Edited to remove map notation like {function -> state}, using function|state now

Comment: Explaining what you are trying to accomplish with this or what problem you think this will help with will probably be the most useful thing for you to do. Additionally, providing a "realistic" example of the kind of thing you want to use this for. My best guess right now is that you're trying to mathematically model some object-oriented programming concepts. As it is, you are either still using notation in non-standard or inconsistent ways. For example, $\{2\}=\{2,2\}$ so it would seem $\{\sigma|1,2\}$ is ill-defined as $\{\sigma|1,2\}=2$ but $\{\sigma|1,2,2\}=4$.

Comment: I am trying to model systems in general or guess you could say I am looking for a systems theory. My end goal is to be able to apply this to complex systems in context of system dynamics, emergence etc. A real life example would be representing physical systems like Newtonian N-bodies or if we are going with the computer science angle, neural networks or linear physical systems analysis for something interdisciplinary between those two. Or anything really. I was studying how to model social opinion dynamics which led to this question

Comment: As for your example, $\sigma$ as I defined it does not collapse the set into a single point like $\{\sigma|1,2\} = 2$ but rather maps to a new value over a morphism of its parent set. I am going for something that allows it to be defined that way also like $\{\sigma|1,2\} \mapsto \{2\}$.

Comment: What's wrong with the mathematical formalisms that already exist in [systems theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_theory) and [system dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_dynamics)? I should have written $\{\sigma|1,2\}\mapsto\{2\}$, but that doesn't address my concern. Why is it not (also) $\{\sigma|1,2\}=\{\sigma|1,2,2\}\mapsto\{4\}$? Does $\{\sigma|1,\sigma|1\}=\{\sigma|1\}$? If so, it's not really clear what it should mean. If not, using this notation and calling it "sets" is confusing. I would avoid repurposing common notation and terminology in this case.

Comment: Existing ones I have found so far are very limited and case-specific to the phenomena they study when they do exist at all. You could show all those depending on how you define $\sigma$ but in my examples, it assumes each element maps to exactly one element per morphism between sets. I guess I can use new terminology but I want to show some concepts on such function-state sets defined over Banach spaces for future work, so want to keep it simple and defined with common notation where possible

Comment: Added some more clarification on how I am defining $\sigma$